# Having trouble figuring out this segmentation fault

Tags: c, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm sure the mistake is obvious, but I sure am having trouble finding it.

Basically I am trying to make a chessboard via 2D array. I am testing its functionality via 8 queens test... it is not functional.

Somehow one of my integer values is getting out of whack, as `gdb` shows:

```
....
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x080487f8 in diagnols (PARAMETER_ONE=0, PARAMETER_TWO=0) at eq1.c:77
77            if (key->board[abc][bcd] == 1) {
(gdb) print abc
4424  // "SHOULD BE" ONE
(gdb) print bcd
4424  // "SHOULD BE" ONE
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x080487f8 in diagnols (PARAMETER_ONE=0, PARAMETER_TWO=0) at eq1.c:77
#1  0x08048873 in check (param1=0, param2=0) at eq1.c:91
#2  0x08048510 in recur (DEPTH=0, WIDTH=0) at eq1.c:99
#3  0x08048919 in main () at eq1.c:152
(gdb)
```

Then here is `diagnols(...)`, which is in:

```
int recur(struct chessboard* key, int DEPTH, int WIDTH) {
    /* other functions above diagnols(...) */
```

diagnols(...):

```
int diagnols(int PARAMETER_ONE, int PARAMETER_TWO) { // returns 0 if good    

    int abc = 0;
    int bcd = 0;
    int counter = 0; // keeps track of conflicting piece occurrences 

    // OTHER CHECKS FIRST... DELETED TO SAVE ROOM

    // checkign diagnol down and to the left
    abc = PARAMETER_ONE+1;
    bcd = PARAMETER_TWO-1;
    while (  (abc>=0)&&(bcd>=0)  ) {
      if (key->board[abc][bcd] == 1) {
        counter++;
      } abc++;
      bcd--;
    }

    // ERROR IN THIS PART
    // checking diagnol down and to the right
    abc = PARAMETER_ONE+1;
    bcd = PARAMETER_TWO+1;
    while (  (abc>=0)&&(bcd>=0)  ) {
      if (key->board[abc][bcd] == 1) { // ERROR
        counter++;
      } abc++;
      bcd++;
    }

    return counter;
  }
```

And `diagnols(...)` is invoked in `recur(...)` in the below function:

```
  int check(int param1, int param2) { // if okay returns 2 
    // other functions
    d = diagnols(param1, param2);
    int total = 0;
    total = (h + v + d); // if okay, equals 2
    return total;
  }
```

For good measure here is my struct:

```
struct chessboard {
  int board[7][7];
};
```

And main:

```
int main() {
  struct chessboard* master = malloc(sizeof(struct chessboard));
  /* i set the board to zero here. used calloc() before */
  recur(master, 0, 0);
  // stuff
}
```

And yes, I realize *diagnol* isn't spelled *diagonal* ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (  (abc>=0)&&(bcd>=0)  ) {
      if (key->board[abc][bcd] == 1) { // ERROR
        counter++;
      } abc++;
      bcd++;
    }
```

It seems that the condition is going to always be true since you are increasing both indexes.

Did you mean < some limit instead?

Comment: D'oh! :) Yup, forgot to put a ceiling on that.